# javascript not working with php code for session timeout checking

Tags: javascript, php, session, alert, setinterval

I'm using the JavaScript below to check if the user session has not expired (with PHP) at intervals of 5 seconds. After logging out from another tab (same browser) or which the current session must have expired, still the code is bringing up the `alert("Logged back in.");` which is supposed to work for active sessions.

```
setInterval(function () {
    var checklogin = "<? if ($this->session->userdata('user_logged_in')) {echo '1';} else {echo '0';} ?>";
    if (checklogin == "1" ){
        alert("Logged back in.");
    } else {
        alert("you are already logged out!");
    } 
}, 5000);
```

Please what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to be doing this with AJAX. The PHP here is just rendered once (on page load).

Comment: sidenote, better to always use `<?php` also you might as well just use `<?=$this->session->userdata('user_logged_in') ? '1' : '0'; ?>`

Comment: @Alex to be doing it with AJAX; how can i achieve that pls ?

Comment: @Loz noted. i've adopted that. And can you give me the link to the place where the duplicate is?

Comment: The link is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The php section of your code will not change at run time. You could, for example, perform an AJAX call to your server to retrieve session information.

**EDIT:**

If you're using jQuery, take a look at: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

If without jQuery, take a look at: [How to make an ajax call without jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: how can i perform an AJAX call to the server pls? so, it will be run at interval, with the code ??